# Jquery Slider - first slide scrolls too fast

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider

Im having a image slider with proggess bar.
https://jsfiddle.net/vandanasrivastava/voe49n8r/1/
The slider is auto rotating. But the problem is, first slide scrolls too fast. Im new to javascript. Any help is much appreciated. Please check below JS fiddle.

```
var currentIndex = 0;// store current pane index displayed
var ePanes = $('#slider .panel'), // store panes collection
time   = 5000,
bar = $('.progress_bar');

function showPane(index){// generic showPane
// hide current pane
ePanes.eq(currentIndex).stop(true, true).fadeOut();
// set current index : check in panes collection length
currentIndex = index;
if(currentIndex < 0) currentIndex = ePanes.length-1;
else if(currentIndex >= ePanes.length) currentIndex = 0;
// display pane
ePanes.eq(currentIndex).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
// menu selection
$('.nav li').removeClass('current').eq(currentIndex).addClass('current');
}
// bind ul links
$('.nav li').click(function(ev){    showPane($(this).index());});
// bind previous & next links
$('.previous').click(function(){    showPane(currentIndex-1);});
$('.next').click(function(){    showPane(currentIndex+1);});
// apply start pane
showPane(0);

function run(){
bar.width(0);
showPane(currentIndex+1);
bar.animate({'width': "+=400"}, time, run);
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on line 24 you're firing `showPane(0)`, but then you run `showPane(currentIndex+1)` on the `run` function just after those.

Also, set on the first line `currentIndex = -1` instead of 0.

So essentially you're running it twice.
Just comment out `showPane(0)` and it should work.